# Class Dictionary in java (data structure)

Tags: java, class, data-structures, dictionary

How to use Class Dictionary in java ?

Comment: From Java API: NOTE: This class is obsolete. New implementations should implement the Map interface, rather than extending this class.

Comment: I completely forgot about the `Dictionary` class! Time for a walk down memory lane...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use it, it's profoundly, thoroughly, obsolete and unnecessary.

Use a Map implementation such as HashMap.

Comment: This assumes he has a choice.

Answer (score 2):

Look at java.util.HashMap and java.util.Map (I understand you are looking for a dictionary equivalent in Java, and not referring to the abstract Dictionary class which is implemented by HashTable)

Comment: I know this but need implementation .

Comment: HashMap *is* an implementation of the Map interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Hashtable.  It extends the Dictionary class.

As for everyone who says it is obsolete, it probably should be but isn't.  It is used in the current OSGi api in the class ServiceRegistration, and OSGi is somewhat popular these days ;-)

Of course, since Hashtable also implements Map, at least you can treat as one in your own code and still pass it in via the OSGi api as needed.

Comment: Something can be heavily used and still be obsolete